# How to pass Dictionary object into generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Updated with fiddle**
This is a similar example, although the fiddle is breaking on both IGatewayRequest/IGatewayResponse and Dictionary and Dictionary - my code actually works and runs successfully with the interfaces but not with the dictionary.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NQ7G8E

I have the set of code below which accepts a request and response type, as well as the request data and then makes a call passing that data to be processed. It works for non-dictionary objects, but it fails with a dictionary object. Can I not pass a dictionary type to a generic type parameter? Is there something different that I have to do for it to work?

Here is the code that takes in the two type parameters and the request, and then calls _service.ParseResponse which is where the error is

```
public IServiceResponse Execute<TRequest,TResponse>(IServiceRequest webRequest) {
    var proxyRequest = _proxy.Call(webRequest)
    var gatewayResponse = _gateway.Send(proxyRequest);
    var serviceResponse = _service.ParseResponse<TRequest, TResponse>(request, (TRequest) proxyRequest, (TResponse) gatewayResponse);
    return serviceResponse;

}
```

I have 2 different classes that implement this method, one where TRequest and TResponse are interfaces that get called like this and works fine

```
serviceResponse = gatewayRequest.Execute<IGatewayRequest,IGatewayResponse>(webRequest);
```

However, as soon as I have a request and response type of Dictionary, and in this case the request type is Dictionary then I get the following compile time

Code:

```
 serviceResponse = gatewayRequest.Execute<Dictionary<string,object>,Dictionary<string,string>>(webRequest);
```

Error:

```
 Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object> to TRequest
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thanks!

**Edit:**
My ParseResponse signature is as follows:

```
public IServiceResponse ParseResponse<TRequest, TResponse>(IWebRequest webRequest, TRequest proxyRequest, TResponse gatewayResponse)
```

Comment: What type is `_service`? Are there any constraints on the first generic type parameter for `_serviceType.ParseResponse()`?

Comment: _service is a class, and the first parameter is a type of IWebRequest. I have a case/switch statement which generates a different _service based off the incoming webRequest parameters.

Comment: I have tried to post a fiddle where you can see what is happening, but the fiddle is showing failures for both the Dictionary and the IGateway calls, even though that works in my code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NQ7G8E

Answer (score 0):

Changed Dictionary to IDictionary, problem solved.